# How do rotation and shifting transformation work in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, transformation

I'm new to TikZ so I was reading the TikZ documentation. On page 43, there is an example like below

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[even odd rule,x=10pt, y=10pt, scale=4]
    \filldraw[fill=yellow!80!black] (0,0) rectangle (1,1)
           [xshift=5pt, yshift=5pt] (0,0) rectangle (1,1)
                        [rotate=30] (-1,-1) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which draws

[image]

I understand how the small rectangles are shifted. The bottom left corner of the rectangle shifted by .5 units right to each axis.

[image]

But I can't figure out how the rotation of the big square works. If we look at the graph below
[image]

the green square is the original square before the roation (`\draw (-1,-1) rectangle (2,2);`) and the black tilted square without filling is the green square rotated 30 degrees. If we shift the black unfilled square 5 units to the positive direction of each axis, the most bottom corner should be at the red circle which is (-0.5,-0.5). But the result doesn't show like I described. How does `shift` and `rotate` work?

Comment: Shifting and rotating accumulate. The center of rotation is `(5pt, 5pt)`, the shifted origin. And the square that is being rotated is not the green one, but the one touching that red circle

Comment: One good side of this design is that it is good at "first-person movement".  You can easily accumulate `[yshift = 1cm]` (move forward 1cm), `[rotate = 30]` (turn left 30 degrees), `[yshift = 2cm]` (move forward 2cm), ...

Comment: To rephrase a crucial part of what Symbol 1 said, *both* the square and its centre of rotation are shifted.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In *TikZ* writting, as in a mathematical composition of functions, say *t* composed with *r* and applied to *a*, which is *t(r(a))*, the function appearing last in the writting process is firstly applied.  Here, for example, *r* acts firstly on *a*, and then *t* acts on the result *g(a)*. Going back to the shift+rotation or rotation+shift, the result depends on which of the two elementary isometries appears last.

In the initial drawing of the question, as for the blue filled square in Figure 1 above, the rotation appears last.  So the black square is rotated with respect to the origin and then the result is translated with the vector *(2.8, 0.8)*.

**Remark** Every rotation, independently of its position in the `\draw` command, is performed with respect to the center *(0, 0)*.

In Figure 2, the two composed isometries are graphically decomposed.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}

\tikzmath{%
  real \dx, \dy, \da, \r, \R;
  \dx = 2.8;
  \dy = .8;
  \da = -23;
  \r = {sqrt(2)}; 
}
\begin{figure}[htb!]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=.1cm, fill opacity=1},
    scale=.8]
    \draw[gray!50] (-2, -2) grid (5, 3);
    \draw[red, ->] (-3, 0) -- (6, 0);
    \draw[red, ->] (0, -3) -- (0, 4);
    
    \draw[very thick](-1, -1) rectangle ++(3, 3);

    \filldraw[fill=blue!90!green, fill opacity=.4]
    [xshift=\dx cm, yshift=\dy cm, rotate=\da]
    (-1, -1) rectangle (2, 2);
    
    \filldraw[fill=violet, fill opacity=.4]
    [rotate=\da, xshift=\dx cm, yshift=\dy cm]
    (-1, -1) rectangle (2, 2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{The blue filled square is issued from the initial question.
    It is the result a rotation of angle $-22^\circ$ with respect to
    the center $(0, 0)$, and then of a translation with the vector
    $(2.8, .8)$.  The red filled square is the result of the
    translation and then the rotation operations applied on the same
    black non filled square.}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[htb!]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=.1cm, fill opacity=1},
    scale=.8]
    \draw[gray!50] (-2, -2) grid (5, 3);
    \draw[red, ->] (-3, 0) -- (6, 0);
    \draw[red, ->] (0, -3) -- (0, 4);
    
    \draw[very thick] (-1, -1) rectangle ++(3, 3);
    \filldraw[fill=blue!90!green, fill opacity=.1][rotate=\da]
    (-1, -1) rectangle ++(3, 3);
    
    \begin{scope}[xshift=\dx cm, yshift=\dy cm]
      \filldraw[fill=blue!90!green, fill opacity=.4][rotate=\da]
      (-1, -1) rectangle ++(3, 3);
    \end{scope}

    \draw (170: \r) arc (170: 250: \r);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  % 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=.1cm, fill opacity=1},
    scale=.8]
    \draw[gray!50] (-2, -2) grid (5, 3);
    \draw[red, ->] (-3, 0) -- (6, 0);
    \draw[red, ->] (0, -3) -- (0, 4);
    
    \draw[very thick](-1, -1) rectangle ++(3, 3);
    
    \filldraw[fill=violet, fill opacity=.1]
    (-1+\dx , -1+\dy ) rectangle ++(3, 3);
    \filldraw[fill=violet, fill opacity=.4][rotate=\da]
    (-1+\dx , -1+\dy ) rectangle ++(3, 3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{The two compositions form Figure 1 decomposed in elementary
    \texttt{TikZ} drawing commands.  In both cases, the center of
    rotation is the origin, the point $(0, 0)$.}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```